# XSL for-each 2 elements warp in container

Tags: xslt

I have an xsl file, where I get content out of templates and need to warp each 2 elements in container, if there are 2 elements.

My code is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output indent="yes" method="html"/>

<xsl:template name="type0">
    <div class="content"></div>    
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="teaser>
    <xsl:param name="pos" select="1" />
    <xsl:call-template name="type0">
        <xsl:with-param name="pos" select="$pos" />
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="frontpage">
    <div class="container">
        <xsl:call-template name="teaser />
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```

The output needs to be like this (if I there are 5 elements created):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

Any idea how this is possible?

**EDIT:**

I've tryed to implement Thomas W.'s suggestion, but it fails with it can't compile stylesheet. Am I doing something work in this code:

```
<xsl:template match="type0" mode="generate-container-content">
    <div class="content"></div>    
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="teaser">
    <xsl:param name="pos" select="1" />

    <div class="container">
        <xsl:template match="type0[position() mod 2 = 1]">
            <xsl:apply-templates select=".|following-sibling::type0[1]" mode="generate-container-content">
                <xsl:with-param name="pos" select="$pos" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:template>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="frontpage">
    <xsl:call-template name="teaser" />
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Your missing a closing quote in the last `name` attribute. What editor are you using? I recommend looking out for something that immediately alerts you to stuff like that.

Comment: I saw that, but still it did not help :( Still getting an error compile stylesheet. I'm using CFEclipse

Comment: Why do you have an `<xsl:template>` inside the `<div>`? That's not valid. Did you mean to put an `<xsl:apply-templates>` there? Then you'd need to make the `<xsl:template>` a sibling of the other `<xsl:template>`s.

Comment: Thanks, I solved it in another way with javascript. The problem I needed solved was to make equal height, but did not work properly in the design. With this [Link](http://codepen.io/micahgodbolt/pen/FgqLc) I made it happen, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Say you have a list of `<someElement>` elements, then you can make use of modes and do the following (see comments for explanation):

```
<!-- Only generate a container for elements at uneven position
  (1st, 3dr, 5th etc.) -->
<xsl:template match="someElement[position() mod 2 = 1]">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Use a different mode for actually creating the content elements 
      We need to use the mode for distinguishing between templates that 
      match elements in the list for creating the container and ones that
      match for creating content. -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select=".|following-sibling::someElement[1]"
      mode="generate-container-content"/>
  </div>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Don't generate anything for any other elements that are not 
  matched by the template above (the even-positioned ones remain) -->
<xsl:template match="someElement"/>

<xsl:template match="someElement" mode="generate-container-content">
  <div class="content">
    Generate whatever the content looks like
  </div>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll have a look at it.

Comment: Sry about the answer - was'nt sure I could do that, sp thank you.